# Print nested list as grid using loops or .join

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing, nested-lists

I am making Connect 4 game as a project and I can only use loops or .join. 
If my 2D list is:

```
    Arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

I want it to be displayed as:

```
     === ===
    | 1 | 2 |
     === ===
    | 3 | 4 |
     === ===
```

I want the code to work for any n*n matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions for this:

```
def print_row(row):
    return ' ' + '=== '*len(row) + ' \n' + '|' + '|'.join(f' {x} ' for x in row) + '|'

def print_board(arr):
    return '\n'.join(print_row(row) for row in arr) + '\n ' + '=== '*len(arr[-1])
```

**Example Usage:**

```
>>> print(print_board([[1,2],[3,4]]))
 === ===  
| 1 | 2 |
 === ===  
| 3 | 4 |
 === === 

>>> print(print_board([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))
 === === ===  
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
 === === ===  
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
 === === ===  
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
 === === ===
```

This code will work for any n*n list (with all elements single characters), assuming `n>0`.